# Incorrect use of parent data widget. expanded widgets must be placed inside flex widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error:

i.e..,  Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
showing error on the mobile screen.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: categoryNames.length,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
                 ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
                TabBar(
                  labelColor:Colors.black,
                  tabs: categoryNames,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      ImageList()
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                /*TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                  ],
                )*/
              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

It's my code, please check and let me know the issue.

Comment: I've just run the code you've posted and I'm not getting the same error, would you be able to post the contents of `categoryNames` or the output of `ImageList()`? The issue is most likely an `Expanded` that's not the direct child of a `Column` or a `Row`, but without more info it's a bit hard to say where exactly it's coming from

Comment: categorynames is just a list of names and Imagelist is a class, issue is with expanded itself is showing but apart from this any alternate is there to acheive tabbarview with tabs

Answer (score 483):

**`Expanded` cannot be used inside a `Stack`.**

You should use `Expanded` only within a `Column`, `Row` or `Flex`

Comment: FWIW, I also got this issue when, after converting a `Column` to a `Stack`, I had a `Spacer` widget as one of the children of the `Stack`. I was scouring my code looking for "Expanded", but there was none.

So basically, make sure you have neither an `Expanded` nor a `Spacer` as a child of your `Stack`.

Answer (score 99):

First Rule: use `Expanded` only within a `column`, `row` or `flex`.

Second Rule: Parent `column` that have expanded child column must be wrapped with expanded as well

Comment: On my case, the issue is because the Expanded/Flexible is not a direct child(ren) in Column's children, but rather inside a GestureRecognizer which is the direct child(ren) of the Column.

Comment: haven't heard a bigger nonsense yet. If expanded can only be a descendant of column, row or flexible how do you suggest we should wrap a column within expanded?

Answer (score 78):

There are many things to get this problem.

For example:

1. Under `ListView` don't use `Spacer` Widget
2. don't use `Positioned` under `Row` or `Column`
3. `Expanded` can only use it must be a descendant of `Column` `Row` `Flex`

Comment: BINGOuuu!  
Specifically I had a `Spacer()` assigned to the `trailing` of a `ListTile` which is inside a `ListView`. It rendered OK but the error was logged and cause for concern. The big problem here was that the stacktrace does not mention my code at all, so it was difficult to track manually, looking at all the `Expanded()` instances.

Example: `ListView( ListTile ( triling: Spacer() ) )` <- This is bad

Answer (score 11):

My issue is because of Expand

```
          child: Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                children: getChildren(cubit.listPerformer, state),
              ),
```

After delete Expand, it works fine.

Comment: this error goes away but `SingleChildScrollView` still doesnt work.

Comment: It needs to look at your code

Comment: @eqrakhattak to make SingleChildScrollView u need to ensure widget have fixed height or expanded height. So in many case before using SingleChildScrollView you need to define the size of widget (height/width depend on vertical/horizontal scroll) using expanded(only in row/column/flex) or sizedbox.

Answer (score 8):

there's no expanded in my code so i found that using `Spacer()` too can cause this error if it's inside a `listview`

Comment: Did you find an alternative to use ```Spacer()``` inside the Scrollable item? I want to keep maximum space before the last column child and I want to eliminate Overflow on the Keyboard popup.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was using `Positioned` inside a column. Removing it solved the problem!

Answer (score 7):

I removed a `Positioned` widget that was inside a `Container` inside a `Stack` and the problem "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" went away.

Comment: It's good to try and help, but in this case there are already a lot of very detailed answers to this question and yours doesn't actually add anything. Before answering have a look at what other people have said, and think about whether you're adding anything new that's clearly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Expanded()** can only be used inside **Row(), Column() and Flex()**

**Flexible()** can only be used within **Row(), Column() and Flex()**.

**Positioned()** can only be used inside **Stack()**.

**TableCell()** can only be used inside **Table()**.

**Two or more Expanded() do not have the same parent.**
Observe the example below, it will certainly give a ParentWidgetError! Because there are two Expanded() within the same widget, there are two Expanded() "competing with each other".
In your specific case, I believe it is the error above. However, I need more details to say with 100% certainty.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(child: child)
    Expanded(child: child)
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the **Expanded**.

You should have to use **Expanded** whenever needed.

Check the below image for reference.

[image: Removed expanded and it works perfect]

Answer (score 2):

when I skip the video, the chewie controller shows these errors when I fix in chewie package error gone.

please fix in material_controls.dart [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUBAe.png)

[remove expanded widget in Stack widget]

```
return MouseRegion(
  onHover: (_) {
    _cancelAndRestartTimer();
  },
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => _cancelAndRestartTimer(),
    child: AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: notifier.hideStuff,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          if (_latestValue.isBuffering)
            const Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            )
          else
            _buildHitArea(),
          _buildActionBar(),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              if (_subtitleOn)
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                      0.0, notifier.hideStuff ? barHeight * 0.8 : 0.0),
                  child:
                      _buildSubtitles(context, chewieController.subtitle!),
                ),
              _buildBottomBar(context),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This Solution works only if you are using Position as a parent of row or column

In my case, I was using Positioned inside a column. Removing it solved the problem!

Else

Always remember to use Expanded in Row, Column or Flex

Answer (score 2):

```
 Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 25, vertical: 20),
                      child: Card(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Expanded(child: _buildDataTable(data, fields)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

give real life to my device
emulator and during other emulator devices working fine

but this is not working on a real device like an Android phone, then follow the rule of

First Rule: Use Expanded only within a column, row, or flex.

Second Rule: Parent columns that have expanded child columns must be wrapped with expanded columns as well.

remove Expanded

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 25, vertical: 20),
                      child: Card(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: _buildDataTable(data, fields),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using Expanded inside a Padding widget. Padding was inside a column but since Expanded was wrapped by a Padding it gave me the error. Simply removing Expanded solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was enclosing an Expanded inside a SizedBox, I just enclosed the Expanded inside a Row and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used Positioned widget without using parent widget Stack. I fixed using parent  widget Stack for Positioned.

```
   return Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
        
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Expanded` as child of scrolling parent like this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        fillOverscroll: true,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.red,height: 100),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(color: Colors.purple,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```