# Flutter Appbar title grey background displaying

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter AppBar custom view, title widget overlay with grey background in Signed build, debug build its working fine.

title widget custom view source code is shared below, please check.

```
_getAppbar(AppTheme themeData) {

return AppBar(
  titleSpacing: 0,
  centerTitle: false,
  leading: Container(
    //color: Colors.blue,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 30.0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        "assets/svg/man.svg",
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
      ),
      //backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
  title: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Expanded(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Hi, Vikky",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 9,
                fontWeight: fontRegular,
                color: Color(themeData.headerNameColor)),
          ),
          Wrap(crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center, children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              size: 12,
              color: Color(themeData.brandColor),
            ),
            Text(
              "Kuzhikkattu Moola",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: fontMedium,
                  color: Color(themeData.textColor)),
            )
          ]),
        ])),
  ),
  backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 0,
);
```

}[image]

[image]

Debug build its working fine, issue only in signed build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is related to **Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget** not about color.
This issue seems only in release mode not in build mode

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Expanded( //Issue is here Incorrect use of Expanded Widget
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Hi, Vikky",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 9,
                fontWeight: fontRegular,
                color: Color(themeData.headerNameColor)),
          ),
          Wrap(crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center, children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              size: 12,
              color: Color(themeData.brandColor),
            ),
            Text(
              "Kuzhikkattu Moola",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: fontMedium,
                  color: Color(themeData.textColor)),
            )
          ]),
        ])),
  ),
```

Try to manage your UI by replacing widget - **Expanded** .
Go through with this link : [Incorrect use of Parent Data Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905388/incorrect-use-of-parent-data-widget-expanded-widgets-must-be-placed-inside-flex)

Comment: This is clearly the reason. But it is unusual for a debug version not to log this issue. This code should not have worked in debug too.