# Force Flutter to Crash, like it would in Release Mode, when "Exception caught by widgets library" or "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget occurs"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

There are tons of questions & answers about specific instances of this issue. My question is more general:

In debug mode, there are no compiler warnings, and the screen looks as it should. Obviously there's a print statement in the console, but that's so easy to miss. In release mode, the widget gets painted totally grey, because of the exception.

How do I either:

- Get Debug mode to treat the exception like it would in Release (aka paint the widget grey, or similar), without actually building for Release.
- Get a compiler warning/error about the issue, or maybe something similar that a separate dependency/linter could provide.

Comment: Can you include a sample code snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: If you put a Positioned widget as a child of a Stack, everything's fine. if you wrap the Positioned widget in a Semantics widget, then everything compiles fine, but you get an exception. Similar to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905388/incorrect-use-of-parent-data-widget-expanded-widgets-must-be-placed-inside-flex

Comment: have you managed to get an answer on this?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
flutter run --release
```

This will run the project in release mode and you can still see the logs

Comment: I appreciate the response! just calling out that I'm specifically hoping for an answer "without actually building for Release", since doing that constantly in development isn't feasible.

Comment: Absolutely. You can also try some packages like linter and define rules onceand when you develop codes it will show warnings of codes that doesnt follow those rules. https://pub.dev/packages/linter