# FirestoreListView inside ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to put `FirestoreListView` inside `ListView` but i recieve some errors.

My code sample:

```
ListView(
    children: [
      // Some stuffs here
      FirestoreListView<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          query: usersQuery,
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
        Map<String, dynamic> user = snapshot.data();
    
        return Text('User name is ${user['name']}');
        },
      )
  ],
  ),
```

The error I got:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
```

After using `FirestoreListView` inside `SizedBox` with height it does not work as i want.

Comment: Does wrapping it with and `Expanded` widget do anything?

Comment: @MendelG If i use it inside `Column` by wrapping with `Expaned` then it works but with `ListView` it gives error.

Comment: what errors does it give?

Comment: @MendelG The error is: `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`

Comment: that's because you can't wrap a `column` in an `Expanded` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905388/incorrect-use-of-parent-data-widget-expanded-widgets-must-be-placed-inside-flex

Comment: But using `Expanded` does solve your issue, however a _different_ issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

ListView and FirestoreListView does the same job for you., you can remove the over ListView and just use FirestoreListView, the itemBuilder function will do the required job for you

Comment: In the `ListView` I have other stuffs to show. I cannot move my stuffs inside `FirestoreListView`.